# My main method has to repeat this 100 times: randomly generate numbers 1 to 12, use getDayInMonth to randomly generate days?

Tags: java, date, random, count, repeat

So this is what i have so far and the class `getDayInMonth` has to remain unchanged and i would like it to count how many times it matches. How do you did it please?

```
public class Real {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int realmonth = 5;
        int realday= 11;
        int count = 0;

        for(int iteration = 1; iteration <=100; iteration ++) {
            Random Month = new Random();
            int month = Month.nextInt(12) + 1;
            if(realmonth == month) count++;
            System.out.println("The correct birthday was found " + count + " times during the 100 iterations.");
        }

    public static int getDayInMonth(int month) {

        final int JANUARY = 1;  final int JULY = 7;
        final int FEBRUARY = 2; final int AUGUST = 8;
        final int MARCH = 3;    final int SEPTEMBER = 9;
        final int APRIL = 4;    final int OCTOBER = 10;
        final int MAY = 5;      final int NOVEMBER = 11;
        final int JUNE = 6;     final int DECEMBER = 12;

        Random dayGenerator = new Random();
        switch (month) {

        case JANUARY: case MARCH: case MAY: case JULY:
        case AUGUST: case OCTOBER: case DECEMBER:
            return dayGenerator.nextInt(31) + 1;

        case APRIL: case JUNE: case SEPTEMBER: case NOVEMBER:
            return dayGenerator.nextInt(30) + 1;

        case FEBRUARY:
            return dayGenerator.nextInt(28) + 1;

        default:
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int iteration = 1; iteration <= 10000; iteration++) {
        Random Month = new Random();
        int month = Month.nextInt(12) + 1;
        // Added call to getDayInMonth
        if (realmonth == month && getDayInMonth(month) == realday) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    // Moved this outside for loop
    System.out.println("The correct birthday was found " + count + " times during the 100 iterations.");
```

To simplify your code you could just randomly select a day of the year i.e. 365 as it seems you are not taking leap years into account

```
    Random r = new Random();
    int realDate = r.nextInt(365) + 1; 
    // Or assign one yourself with 
    // LocalDate.of(2013, 4, 31).getDayOfYear();

    int count = 0;
    for (int iteration = 1; iteration <= 10000; iteration++) {
        int randDate = r.nextInt(365) + 1;
        if (randDate == realDate) {
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The Quest says `getDayInMonth` method cannot be changed. Must be a homework assignment challenge.

Comment: Saw that later, first part however is still as requested :)

Answer (score 0):

You are close. The problem is how to call the `getDayInMonth` method. This is a method, not a class as you incorrectly state in the Question.

This method is `static` meaning it is independent of instances of this class. In other words, not object-oriented. So we call it by the class name.

```
int dayOfMonth = Real.getDayOfMonth( month ) ;
```

Expand your `if` to test both `month` and `dayOfMonth`.

```
boolean monthMatch = ( month == realMonth ) ;
boolean dayOfMonthMatch = ( dayOfMonth == realDay ) ;
if ( monthMatch && dayOfMonthMatch ) { count++ ; }
```

Note that by convention Java programmers usually include the curly braces in an `if` statement, even for a single line.

## Naming conventions

In Java, instance are named with lowercase first letter. So your `Random Month` should be `Random month`. But you already have such a variable name, so make it `Random monthRandom`.

Also, I would replace that with:

```
int month = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 1 , 13 ) ;
```

We use 13 there because the bound is *exclusive*, so 12 + 1 = 13. See the [class documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt-int-int-).

## java.time

By the way, in real work rather than school assignment, we would use the java.time classes for this problem, such as [`Month`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) and [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html).

Comment: When the piece of code, "int dayOfMonth = Real.getDayOfMonth( month ) ;" is added it states that month cannot be resolved to a varible which was the issue i was having in the first place, how do i fix this so it is recoginized?

Comment: @Dave You have two vars both named the same - very bad. Fix your var names, and reread the "Naming Conventions" section in my Answer.

Comment: It still isnt working and i have no idea why, no variables have the same name and there is still the message saying 'month' cannot be recognised when using this code...

Comment: @Dave When in doubt, start over, one line at a time, compiling as you go.